# A method other than client library to run a custom scheduler in kubernetes

Tags: api, kubernetes, scheduler

I would like to run a *custom scheduler* parallel with *default scheduler* in kubernetes control plane but NOT through client libraries like python or java.
Since scheduler should be able to watch the API server, I am not sure how to do it. In python-client library function `watch.Watch()` is responsible to contact the API server but as I said, I wouldn't use client library. Is there any option to do it?

Comment: In principle you can use raw HTTP calls...but it will be much easier to use one of the existing client libraries, and you'll probably effectively wind up rebuilding a client library in your own code.  What leads to this requirement?

Comment: Please don't use code font for pieces of text which really aren't code at all. the *only* piece of text in your question which should be in code font is `watch.Watch()`

Comment: Thanks David. Is there any source or docment to give the idea for starting? It's just a test.

Comment: Right, there's still no indication of *why* you'd want to re-implement this yourself rather than using an existing (tested and widely-used) client library though. If we don't know why you've got this unusual constraint, it's entirely possible that any answers provided might not meet your requirements.

Comment: You are right @JonSkeet. This is a part of my research and project. As I said, the task is running a custom scheduler in control plan without using python-client library (My code is in python). what is your suggestion?

Comment: Firstly, edit the question to explain your highly unusual requirements. But then you should basically research the k8s API docs - I expect there will be examples of the raw JSON.